# RStudio like authentication for Jupyterhub

Tags: django, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to configure Jupyterhub using [these instructions.](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/wiki/Installation-of-Jupyterhub-on-remote-server)

However, instead of Github authentication I would like to use either

1) Rstudio server like authentication where credentials are the same as linux user ones, or

2) I would like to integrate it with my Django app where the users can login through the Django app login credentials. Something like Coursera has done here: https://hub.coursera-notebooks.org/hub/login (maybe with a different framework)

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Rstudio server like authentication where credentials are the same as linux user ones

This is the default behavior of JupyterHub, which uses the PAMAuthenticator to login with existing system usernames and passwords.

> I would like to integrate it with my Django app where the users can login through the Django app login credentials.

This would mean writing an [Authenticator](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authenticators.html). If your django app is an OAuth provider, you can use the [oauthenticator](https://github.com/jupyterhub/oauthenticator) package, which implements logging in with OAuth2. You can write your own subclass of the base OAuthenticator that talks to your application, using the various implementations in that repo as an example.

If your application is *not* an OAuthenticator, you may need to start from the base Authenticator class and define `.authenticate()` method.

If you *proxy* JupyterHub behind your django app, the simplest way to authenticate is to check a header that the proxy sets for authenticated users (and make sure that only authenticated requests arrive at the Hub). The [RemoteUserAuthenticator](https://github.com/cwaldbieser/jhub_remote_user_authenticator) is one such example that relies on the REMOTE_USER header set by Apache during login.

Comment: How can i setup jupyterhub so that users can login using system users and passwords? I'm trying to configure it using the instructions on this link: https://github.com/ozancaglayan/jupyterhub-installation
But it's not letting me login using system credentials.

Comment: If you type `sudo jupyterhub` with no configuration, system users and passwords can be used. The user running the Hub needs permission to read the password database, e.g. root or a member of the `shadow` group on certain distros.

Comment: sudo jupyterhub says 'command not found'. Simply typing jupterhub with sudo starts the server but authentication not working. My jupterhub is in .local/bin/jupyterhub

Comment: ok, typing `sudo $(which jupyterhub)` runs the server but now I get a 500 error and it says _Unhandled error starting demo's server: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jupyterhub-singleuser'_

Comment: You will need to ensure that these commands are on your PATH. Using `sudo -s` is one way to do this.

Comment: `sudo jupyterhub` is not working but using `sudo -s` before `jupyterhub` is. How can I put these commands in /etc/rc.local file so that jupyterhub starts up automatically when the system boots?